# javax / websocket / CloseReason $ CloseCode

Tags: jmeter, java-websocket

I refer to this tutorial
 https://blazemeter.com/blog/websocket-testing-apache-jmeter

I run **websocket** java in **jmeter** ,but **jmeter log** responsed like this -

```
jmeter.JMeter: Uncaught exception: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax / websocket / CloseReason $ CloseCode
```

I do not know how to solve this problem ?
[Stacktrace](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ca3Np.png)
Thanks in advance!

Comment: java code (websocket)  run in jmeter

Answer (score 0):

Any "NoClassDefFoundError" usually means that either you don't have the relevant .jar in [JMeter classpath](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#classpath) or you haven't restarted JMeter after dropping the .jar into its lib or lib/ext folder.

I would suggest the following:

1. Get the latest JMeter version (it is 3.0 at the moment)
2. Install [JMeter Plugins Manager](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-install-jmeter-plugins-manager)
3. Install WebSocket Sampler via the plugins manager

---

If you're trying to run JMeter via JSR223 Sampler and Java code example - the same, make sure [Tyrus libraries](https://tyrus.java.net/) are in JMeter classpath and JMeter is restarted after that.